# Loading all entities from a table with Hibernate crashes application

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I was attempting to grab all non-deleted objects from a MySQL table I have using Hibernate, but since there are so many rows in the table it (unsurprisingly) crashed my application.  There are roughly 280k items returned from the query for each category.

What can I do to mitigate this?  Is there some sort of functionality offered within Hibernate that can cope with this situation?  Or do you have any ideas as to how I could change my logic to avoid this?

**Method in question:**

```
public void removeCategory(ItemCategory category)
{
    User user = userAuthentication.getLoggedInUser();
    Set<Category> deletedCategories = category.orphan();
    sessionManager.commit();

    for (Category cat : deletedCategories)
    {
        List<Item> itemsInCategory = itemDAO.getItemsInCategory(category);
        reindexer.reindex(cat, ReindexerPriority.HIGH);
        reindexer.reindex(itemsInCategory, ReindexerPriority.LOW);
    }
}
```

**itemDAO#getItemsInCategory(category):**

```
public List<Items> getItemsInCategory(final ItemCategory category)
{
                                        // HQL here, not SQL
    final Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT item" + 
                                            "FROM Item item, ItemCategory c" + 
                                            "WHERE asset in elements(c.items)" + 
                                            "AND c = :category" + 
                                            "AND item.dateDeleted IS null");
    query.setEntity("category", category);
    return query.list();
}
```

Comment: `FROM Item item, ItemCategory c` you are using the old comma join syntax that is over 25 year old. Very hard to read and to see if you are using a INNER JOIN or a CROSS JOIN there.. i don't see `item.id = c.item_id` or something like that in the WHERE statement so i think your query using a CROSS JOIN.. Are you sure you need a CROSS JOIN over there?.. i strongly advice you to use the `....INNER JOIN ... ON ...` syntax instead.

Comment: try to execute you sql query in mysql to see how fast is it  then we decide what's exactly wrong

Comment: Operate in batches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of ways you can operate on large result sets.

As [Pace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202694/pace) mentions, the first is to operate in batches.  You can easily do this by executing the same query in a loop but specifying an offset and limit condition.  This is also commonly referred to as using pagination to get a smaller slice of data and operating on the larger data set in intervals.

So the first thing is to change your method to allow you to ask it to give you a page slice rather than all the items:

```
public List<Items> getItemsByPage(int page, int pageSize) {
  return session.createQuery( "..." )
    .setFirstResult( ( page - 1 ) * pageSize )
    .setMaxResults( pageSize )
    .getResultList();
}
```

The next thing is to use this in a loop and invoke your `reindexer` based on the returned subset lists you get:

```
int page = 1;
for ( List<Items> items = getItemsByPage( page, 100 ); !items.isEmpty(); ++page ) {
  reindexer.reindex( items, ReindexerPriority.LOW );
  // make sure to clear the session to avoid out of memory with L1C
  session.clear();
}
```

Another way would be to reimplement the above and use a `ScrollableResults` object instead, which would allow you to execute a single query rather than multiple queries and instead stream the result set back row-by-row.

```
List<Items> batch = new ArrayList<>();
final ScrollableResults results = session.createQuery( ... ).scroll();
while ( results.next() ) {
  batch.add( results.get( 0 ) );
  if ( ( batch.size() % 100 ) == 0 ) {
    reindexer.reindex( batch, ReindexerPriority.LOW );
    batch.clear();
    session.clear();
  }
}

// handle left-overs of < 100 on last batch to process.
if ( !batch.isEmpty() ) {
 reindexer.reindex( batch, ReindexerPriority.LOW );
 batch.clear();
 session.clear();
}
```

In both cases, its important to be mindful of the L1C (first level cache).  Hibernate maintains an in-memory cache of all loaded and attached entities and so as you load data from the database, particularly in bulk, you need to be mindful of this cache and evict/clear from it periodically to avoid running into `OutOfMemory` exceptions; hence why you see my usage of `Session#clear` in spots.